# clojure - presence of a given set of keys in a clojure map

Tags: clojure, destructuring

There is a map like this

```
{:buyers [{:name "James" :city "Berlin"} {:name "Jane" :city "Milan"}]
:sellers [{:name "Dustin" :city "Turin" :age "21"} {:name "Mark" :city "Milan"}]}
```

and I need to check only for `:sellers` that all the keys `:name, :city and :age` are present and if one is missing drop
that map all together and have a new structure as below:

```
{:buyers [{:name "James" :city "Berlin"} {:name "Jane" :city "Milan"}]
:sellers [{:name "Dustin" :city "Turin" :age "21"}]}
```

I came across [validateur](https://github.com/michaelklishin/validateur) and I am trying to use it like:

```
(:require [validateur.validation :as v])

(def my-map {:buyers [{:name "James" :city "Berlin"} {:name "Jane" :city "Milan"}]
             :sellers [{:name "Dustin" :city "Turin" :age "21"} {:name "Dustin" :city "Milan" :age "" } {:city "Rome" :age "22"}]})

(defn valid-seller? [mp]
  (let [v-set (v/validation-set
               (v/presence-of #{:name :city :age}))]  
    (fmap vec (v-set mp))))

(map valid-seller? (:sellers my-map))

=> ({} {:age ["can't be blank"]} {:name ["can't be blank"]})
```

But I do not know how to update my map so missing keys or nil values be dropped

Comment: what if a seller has more keys than required?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @coredump more keys than required are not my concern now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the code more readable, I created a new predicate, `valid-seller?`, and put validation there. You can use any of these versions:

Pure Clojure:

```
(defn valid-seller? [m]
  (every? #(contains? m %) [:name :city :age]))
```

[Spec](https://github.com/clojure/spec.alpha):

`[org.clojure/spec.alpha "0.3.218"]`, require `[clojure.spec.alpha :as spec]`

```
(defn valid-seller? [m]
  (spec/valid? (spec/keys :req-un [::name ::city ::age]) m))
```

[Malli](https://github.com/metosin/malli) (if you also want to test type of values):

`[metosin/malli "0.8.9"]`, require `[malli.core :as malli]`

```
(defn valid-seller? [m]
  (malli/validate [:map
                   [:name :string]
                   [:city :string]
                   [:age :string]] m))
```

Then I used this predicate:

```
(update {:buyers [{:name "James" :city "Berlin"} {:name "Jane" :city "Milan"}]
         :sellers [{:name "Dustin" :city "Turin" :age "21"} {:name "Mark" :city "Milan"}]}
        :sellers
        #(filter valid-seller? %))
=>
{:buyers [{:name "James", :city "Berlin"} {:name "Jane", :city "Milan"}],
 :sellers ({:name "Dustin", :city "Turin", :age "21"})}
```

After your answer, I think you should use Malli, as it also checks the type of values. You can use [`some?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some_q) for any non-nil value:

```
(defn valid-seller? [m]
  (malli/validate [:map
                   [:name some?]
                   [:city some?]
                   [:age some?]] m))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(let [data {:buyers  [{:name "James" :city "Berlin"} {:name "Jane" :city "Milan"}]
            :sellers [{:name "Dustin" :city "Turin" :age "21"} {:name "Mark" :city "Milan"}]}]
    (update data :sellers #(filter (every-pred :name :city :age) %)))
```

Comment: As usual, Clojure's truthiness means you need to be more careful if you want a truly general answer. What if one of the maps contains `nil` or `false` as a value for the relevant keys? Currently you're dropping those maps. Maybe that's what you want, but usually it's not really. I would use `every?` and `contains?` instead of relying on `every-pred` and maps' lookup behavior.

Comment: @amalloy That's a good point. In fact, I have been looking for a validation function for `:sellers` key and for the starter, I want to check if all keys are present and do not have a `nil` value, but `contains?` would return  `true` if the key has a `nil` value, right?

Comment: @Razz Right. Clojure's function for "is this not nil" is `some?`, as demonstrated in Martin Půda's answer.